# Network manager broken after update

Tags: internet

After one of the latest updates and a reboot my network manager is not able to start anymore, dmesg tells me that it gets killed every time it wants to start. How can I fix that? No internet is a pretty huge problem for me...

Comment: Try using this guide from How-To Geek http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I even do not know which packages are broken, that is the problem. A live CD is not working, either (keyboard stops working as soon as I log in)

Comment: the packages that the answers on this page list http://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet

Comment: That solved it, thanks! Interestingly I did not use the "proposed" packages...

Comment: Added it as answer. Mark it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and downgrading the `libnl` packages worked too.

I rebooted using a live USB , downloaded `libnl-3-200-3.2.21-1_amd64.deb`, `libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb` and `libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb` from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/ , installed it using `dpkg -i` and rebooted.

Internet should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following to downgrade the network manager

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-200=3.2.21-1 libnl-route-3-200=3.2.21-1 libnl-genl-3-200=3.2.21-1
```

Comment: You should also add the offline version, this version will not work for me.

Comment: Which version worked for you

Comment: The offline-version, after I had no internet any more

Comment: @arc_lupus Is it the one from Howtogeek or AskUbuntu

Comment: @arc_lupus I have added the offline version